# what does this sentence mean and what is the structure of it?

Tags: grammar

John never did **one thing for more than three days at a time.**

Is this like
one thing at a time for more than three days?

Comment: at a time modifies one thing?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of phrase is generally used to describe someone who just can’t “sit still” and dedicate themselves to one thing. Here, it means that whatever activity John does, he only does for three days at most before he moves on to something else.